# preg_replace put captured digit doesn't work

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I think I have made a bad mistake...

It's the input:

```
http://www.example.com/do.php?action=5&say=text
http://www.example.com/do.php?action=8&say=text
http://www.example.com/do.php?action=10&say=text
```

I want to put another parameter after `action`:

```
preg_replace('/action=[0-9]/', 'action=$1&param=test', $text);
```

but its output is:

```
http://www.example.com/do.php?action=&param=test&say=text
http://www.example.com/do.php?action=&param=test&say=text
http://www.example.com/do.php?action=&param=test&say=text
```

as you see, the `action` values have removed.

Where's my mistake?

Comment: You haven't actually captured the action. Put parenthesis around it. `action=([0-9])`

Comment: You don't need to specifically add it after the action parameter, you could just tack it on the end with an $text .= 'param=test';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$1` is a substring match, and starts with the first parenthesis.  So to use it would be `/actions=([0-9]+)/` to capture the digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/do.php?action=10&say=tex" ;
$url = preg_replace('/action=(\d+)/', "action=$1&param=test", $url);
echo $url ;
```

Output

```
http://www.example.com/do.php?action=10&param=test&say=tex
```